# How I pass params from Jenkins to build.gradle?

Tags: android, jenkins

I want to pass value to my build.gradle file through jenkins (build with params).

I have a String and I need to use this String params to make my release ?

Answer (score 1):

Parametrized builds provide those parameters as environmental variables, like `$PARAM_NAME`. Use your favorites gradle method of getting environmental variables, like `System.getenv('PARAM_NAME')` or `environmentString = "$System.env.PARAM_NAME"`

Answer (score 1):

In *General* configuration set **"This project is parameterized"** checkbox to true, and set String/stash/choice/int parameter as you wish for , the *name* field is your variable name. In your dev project , in the gradle file just grab this variable by calling simple getEnv method.

```
String inputFromJenkins = System.getenv('VARIABLE_NAME')
println('VARIABLE_NAME = ' + inputFromJenkins)
```

for extra documentation: [gradle env variables documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_environment_variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin `This build is Parameterized` and select `string Parameter` int that. In this you can define parameter name and value. Suppose `PARA` is your parameter name and `value` is its default value, then you can pass this value to build.gradle as `$PARA`. For more details see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build.