# How to pass params from Jenkins script to gradle

Tags: jenkins, gradle, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I got this code from my `Jenkins` groovy script:

```
./gradlew -PgroupParam='123' -PversionParam=${params.versionParam} clean build --info
```

I want to know how I we use these parameters (groupParam, versionParam) in my `gradle.build` file?

What is the best practice for it ?

In my `gradle.build` I tried to get them like this and it returned `null`:

```
def groupParam = System.getProperty("groupParam")
def versionParam = System.getProperty("versionParam")
```

And also this approach returned the same:

```
def groupParam = System.getenv("groupParam")
def versionParam = System.getenv("versionParam")
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters passed can be accessed using method `project.getProperty(String)`. In your case you can use `project.getProperty('groupParam')` and `project.getProperty('versionParam')`.

`getProperty(String)` will return `MissingPropertyException` incase the property does not exist so it is better to use menthod `hasProperty(String)` before you use `getProperty()`.

```
if(project.hasProperty('groupParam')) {
  // do this
}
```

Comment: Good point, but I think that the params are not passed, how can I debug or check why it's happened ?

Comment: try using --debug to see if the values are passed or not.

Comment: Also a similar post already exist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813967/how-i-pass-params-from-jenkins-to-build-gradle

Comment: It's not a duplication. Is there any other approach to get the value that I need?